# Time Now() with TimeZone setup

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I am adding data in database with time. I am using Now() for get current time like below in my query.

```html
$upd_qry = "update tbl_quotes 
                set qu_status='".$_GET['status']."', qu_time=NOW()              
                where _quid='".$_GET['quotes_id']."'";
  $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$upd_qry);
```

But I have server in USA and I need Asia Timezone. How can I use Custom timezone with Now() ?

Thanks

Comment: Is qu_time a DATETIME or a TIMESTAMP column?

Comment: @Jarzon its DATETIME column....Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use  `CONVERT_TZ (dt, from_tz,to_tz)`

```
CONVERT_TZ(now(),'US/Eastern','Asia/Tokio');
```

you must check for your  from_tz and to_tz